# Как сделать несколько различных терминалов в Visual Studio Code и сохранить их для следующих запусков редактора?

Tags: visual-studio-code

В Visual Studio Code есть возможность запускать консоли.
Сейчас VSC запускает мне стандартную консоль, cmd.exe. А я хочу добавить в список гитбаш и использовать сразу две.

В правой части, в панели Terminal есть выпадающий список с консолями, где сейчас только cmd.exe и кнопка "новый терминал", при нажатии на которую создаются ещё cmd.exe.
Зайдя в files-preferences-settings-terminal и найдя файл config.json можно заменить путь с cmd.exe до нужной консоли гит-баш, которая добавится при нажатии на кнопку "новый терминал", теперь в выпадающем списке будут две консоли, cmd и git-bush, как мне и нужно.

Но при выходе из редактора список сбрасывается и в выпадающем меню остается последняя указанная консоль. Как сделать что бы при выходе хотя бы выпадающий список с консолями сохранялся, а еще лучше что бы весь блок терминал остался как при выходе (размеры окон терминалов и их расположение)

Comment: возможно подойдет [расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, которое упрощает запуск двух консолей, в моём случае консолей cmd.exe и git-bash. Данный способ не идеальный, но позволяет запустить две консоли в 3 клика и сохранить список консолей для текущего проекта при перезапуске.

Пожалуйста, если вы найдете как улучшить мой вариант, оставьте комментарий или напишите лично мне.

---

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
*(Способ работает по такой схеме, в которой стандартной консолью у вас задан git-bash, иначе как дополнительная консоль git-bash почему то открывается вне редактора.)*

Как подсказали в комментарии, подойдёт расширение "Terminals Manager", автора "Fabio Spampinato".

1) Запускаем VSC. Убедимся, что мы находимся в папке своего проекта, именно для него мы создаем список консолей. Как сделать это глобально я не знаю.
2) Устанавливаем расширение
3) Открываем консоль VSC ctrl+shift+p
4) Вводим: "Terminals: Edit Configuration", откроется файл terminal.json
5) впишем простейшие настройки  для второго терминала. В моём случае **cmd.exe**.
`{
  "autorun": true,
  "terminals": [
    {
      "name": "cmd",
      "shellPath": "C://Windows//System32//cmd.exe"
    }
  ]
}`
6) Перезапускаем редактор
7) В панели терминалов (ctrl+ё) справа видим выпадающее меню, в котором и будут две наши консоли.

---

PS
В папке проекта появится папка .vscode, в которой хранятся конфиги наших настроек.
После запуска VSC в выпадающем меню не сразу отображаются оба терминала, у меня задержка около 1-2 секунд, пока редактор прогружается.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам уже не нужно, но на всякий случай вот ссылка на метод, который позволяет настроить терминалы по умолчанию в VSC:

https://zencod.ru/articles/first-step-git

Если я правильно понял Вашу проблему

Цитата:

По умолчанию консоль VS Code в Windows запускает стандартную командную строку Windows, которая не может работать с GIT, чтобы все работало нужно запустить терминал bash, для этого выполним следующие действия:

-Убедимся, что ранее нами был скачан и установлен git, подробнее данный процесс был описан выше.

-Запускаем Visual Studio Code.

-Зажимаем сочетание клавиш Ctrl + Shift + P вводим open user setting и из выпадающего меню выбираем Open User Settings.

-В параметры поиска вводим terminal.integrated.shell.windows и заменяем cmd.exe на C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe (если вы установили git в другую директорию то ссылка будет иметь вид относительно установленной вами директории).

-Перезагружаем Visual Stuio Code

-Открываем терминал и проверяем, что запущен bash терминал

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

По пути %AppData%\Code\User есть файлик settings.json, там можно в разделе terminal.integrated.profiles.windows скопировать один из существующих терминалов, например Command Prompt, а в "args": [] добавить "/k", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" - для подгрузки переменных окружения как в "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" от Visual Studio. Дальше остаётся лишь выбрать его при использовании или вообще по умолчанию.
В принципе можно в самом файлике в самом низу и забить новый профиль по умолчанию в строке "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "название профиля по умолчанию"